# Setting up PHP on Domino Server

Tags: php, lotus-domino

I am trying to install php5.3 on a Domino server.

I have followed the instructions [here](http://www-10.lotus.com/ldd/46dom.nsf/0/b5e04f0dae366e6585256cd200715513?OpenDocument) and [here](https://www-304.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21099845) to no avail.

I continually get:

> Http Status Code: 500 Reason: Unable to process request, CGI script
>   failed to generate a response

I have set the `cgi.force_redirect = 0` as well as the `doc_root` in `php.ini`.

Is there some sort of thing I have to do to restart PHP? I have restarted the domino web server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is installing PHP as "Other CGI Webserver" Not "No Webserver"